# Aptana error since auto upgrade on Mac Yosemite

Tags: aptana

I searched for this and found similar issues but none of the suggestions worked so I going to throw this out here.

I let Aptana auto upgrade and after the upgrade when I try to connect, I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAEZp.png

If I keep going I eventually get an error about ssh and then also get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8K2l.png

I tried removing and reinstalling aptana from scratch with no success.  I am running Yosemite, is there any known java compatibility issues with Yosemite?